# Is there an abbreviation for "Professors" plural, in a greeting at the top of a formal letter?

Tags: formality, abbreviations, letter-writing

I am writing a letter to two professors.  Normally I abbreviate "Professor" to "Prof." in the greeting.  Is there a way to do that when I need the plural?  Or do I have to write out "Professors X and Y"?

Comment: Tangentially addressed in [How to address (specifically, say thank you to) multiple professors and doctors](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/480918/191178)

Comment: I've always wondered about _Messrs._ Should there be a _Pressrs_?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there an abbreviation for "Professors" plural, in a greeting at the top of a formal letter?

Yes, according to [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/prof#:%7E:text=%20also%20prof.,a%20written%20abbreviation%20for%20professor.):

> **Prof.**
> Also *prof.*
> Word forms: plural **Profs**

The plural form of *Prof.* (Professor) is *Prof**s**.* (Professor**s**).

---

Here are two (random) examples of *Profs.* being used:

> Dear **Profs.** Lee and Winn,
>
> Thank you both for your valuable comments on the manuscript. We greatly appreciate your time and
> consideration, which has helped us to vastly improve the manuscript. [...]
>
> ([Source](https://storage.googleapis.com/plos-corpus-prod/10.1371/journal.pone.0235782/1/pone.0235782.s001.pdf?X-Goog-Algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&X-Goog-Credential=wombat-sa%40plos-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com%2F20220712%2Fauto%2Fstorage%2Fgoog4_request&X-Goog-Date=20220712T191436Z&X-Goog-Expires=86400&X-Goog-SignedHeaders=host&X-Goog-Signature=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))

> Dear **Profs.** Garcia-Olmo, Strom, and Tarnawski,
>
> We would like to thank you and the reviewers for the positive remarks
> concerning our article [...]
>
> ([Source](https://www.f6publishing.com/forms/main/DownLoadFile.aspx?Type=Digital&TypeId=6&id=10.3748%2Fwjg.v23.i5.853&FilePath=E40FF74FCBCDCFEE5B981026DA93DFBD01AF46A3915322E4E47B5435409249132B526C48F364C3DE5277F32684BCCFD24A2FA578AEA6E4AB215D18AA010FB9BA5C7F0A0740E39538) [Download required])